# PHP File modifies log file, but nothing is written?

Tags: php

```
<?php
define('LOG','testfolder/test.html');

$fp = fopen(LOG, 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $_ENV['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'] . "\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

While using this code the test.html gets modified at the right times, but nothing is written but blank space. What's the coding error here?

PHP file has `644` permissions, `test.html` has `744` permissions.

Comment: The most logical explanation would be that  `$_ENV['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'` is empty, no?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_ENV['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']);` output?

Comment: Check also in `$_SERVER` for the value you're looking for.  Apache's docs are lacking when it comes to what circumstances `REDIRECT_` gets prepended.  `var_dump($_SERVER); var_dump($_ENV);`

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? Also, you can user file_put_contents()